# I am trying to redirect user after login to welcome page, it takes me to welcome page and again re directs me back to login page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am trying to take user to welcome page after logging in. but react doesnot take it to the welcome page, instead, automatically goes back to the login page.

```
handleLogins(event) {

fetch(`http://localhost:5000/user/get?email=abc@gmail.com&password=abc`)

.then((response) => { 

  return response.json() 

}).then((response) => {

  this.setState({
    User_FirstNameNew: response.data[0].User_FirstName,

    User_LastNameNew : response.data[0].User_LastName,

    toWelcome: true

  })
    ReactDOM.render((
      <Router>
        <Welcome/>
      </Router>
    ), document.getElementById('root'))
});
}
```

Comment: It goes to welcome page for a brief period and comes back.

Comment: PLease paste the code for welcome page and login page also

Comment: Your welcome page has any redirect to login page, I guess for going back to login page for unauthenticated users. Perhaps that piece of the code is getting executed. How are you ensuring that the user is authenticated (using cookie, local storage field etc)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi I figured out that I used form tag and button with type as submit. This caused the redirection to somehow come back to the same page. I changed the type of the button and it worked well. Can someone explain this behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

How are you redirecting from your login page to welcome?

Make sure you're doing something
`this.props.location.push('/welcome');`

Also, if you're checking `isUserLoggedIn` on welcome page and passing the value as a prop, you have to update the prop first and redirect later. Share some reference code regarding this logic in from your source.